# In Javascript, how to load images from project file dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, html

In a HTML website project, I have a directory named House_img contains several images.I don't know the specific number of the pictures. How could I load them and print them out dynamically ,after adding a new pic into the directory using javascript?

Comment: You can't do it only with front-end JavaScript (and that's a good thing, in a security point of view). You need to read the contents of the directory server-side (with something like PHP, NodeJS, Java, Python...), and send this list to the client, either directly in the HTML, or in JSON

Comment: Welcome Jessie, please follow [this guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) in order to make your question. I can already tell you that you will not be able to achieve that without nodejs or other backend tool to access your files. I suggest you install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org) and use [readDir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to build a list of your images. Good luck!

Comment: @blex That is not completely true.  If that folder is map with read access to anonymous, he could use AJAX to get the file list and process it.

Comment: It is possible, but you should think if it could become a security issue later on. Mapping the folder with a read access and using AJAX, you could do something like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it only with front-end JavaScript.
You should install a server and use PHP to read or/and writing files because PHP is designed for these purposes.
Or simply install XAMPP (If you're using Windows or MacOS) or LAMPP (If you're using Linux).

Comment: But what if the directory is in my project file? I needn't turn to local to find it?

Comment: For instance, there is a project called A and has a sub directory called img. What i need is just iterate the element in img and do some operations like put them in an array. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Which element??